# Get full archive node data

Tags: go-ethereum, chaindata

I am synchronizing the archive node of the ethereum. Syncronization speed depends on the speed of the ssd disk and synchronizes with the speed 0.3 blocks per second. Now the 2700000 block is coming. It should take about 1 week.

Is it possible to get archive of chaindata directory or export file? Somebody posted a torrent file, but torrent is unavailable at the moment.

Comment: geth has export/import commands I've never used them. Around 2.7M and 3.2M are the DoS attacks so it will take longer to process even on SSD.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need export file to use import command. Where i can download it?

Comment: You need a fullnode, but in any case the problem is not download the blocks but processing all the transactions. It is explained by geth developers in this [github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16796#issuecomment-391649278).

Comment: @user1941407 did you manage to build such node so I can download it?

Comment: It takes 3 weeks to download archive node. I have not this data at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a paid (small fee) verified copy from http://archivenode.net or http://getblockchain.download or http://download.myethereumdatabase.net or http://get.myethereumdatabase.net

If you don’t want to pay for network costs, you also have the option to contribute to the source code of open‐source projects.

Comment: Why are these torrents > 7 TiB big, but the Eth chain is < 2 TiB?

Comment: @Markus full archival nodes requires mode data.

Comment: Should be about 700 GB according to https://ycharts.com/indicators/ethereum_chain_full_sync_data_size

Comment: @Markus this chart is for full nodes. Please check Etherscan, which although is not for full archival nodes, contains data size history for archive nodes (archive is not full archive).